# nested attributes with one-to-one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, one-to-one

I'm sitting here now for 8 hours to figure out how that works: I'm trying to modify the example in http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 into a one-to-one relationship.

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :question, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :question
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

Controller:

```
def new  
  @survey = Survey.new  
  @survey.questions.build  
end
```

It works great if I use a one-to-many relationship like:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's failing and where? Can you post your view code or some errors?

Answer (score 2):

Try @survey.build_question instead of @survey.questions.build.

I think that is the right way to build questions when you use a one-to-one relationship.